# Its possible to encrypt dll code?

Tags: c++, dll, encryption

So, I'm developing an anticheat on c++ with dll module. But, so many hackers, can bypass then looking the code.

When I build, I set it to Release... its the incorrect mode or I can encrypt the dll code?

Comment: Hackers can always crack your code whatever you do. The best thing you can do is you write your code like, it is more profitable to not cheat when compared to the time and effort spent on hacking.

Comment: Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Are you willing to consider a third party product?  If so [NetLib Encryptionizer](https://netlibsecurity.com) supports DLL Encryption, for both Managed and Unmanaged DLLs.  (Disclaimer: I am with NetLib Security).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that you are going to be doing the decryption on the client machine to use the dll, the decryption code will have to be somewhere within you application and any good hacker/reverse engineer will still be able to figure it out. Once it is decrypted it will be place within the memory and from there all it takes is a dump of the memory to get a copy of the unencrypted dll.

Comment: Ya, the same hacker, can by pass every time my antihacker, but i'm including it inside the .exe application and he still passing...

Comment: anything that you put inside the exe, resources, imports, all of it can be modified with things like ida, ollydbg, etc.  They will find a way to find it.  The only to truly prevent cheating in games are server side checks or even have the entire game server side.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll try to develop a server-side app. Thanks for the hint.